# PyQt - QDialogButtonBox signals and tool tip

Tags: python, pyqt

I got a couple of questions regarding qDialogButtonBox. While my code still works, I believed that there are a few parts that can be better refined/ I am not finding much info online

```
class testDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init_(self, parent=None):
        ...
        self.init_ui()
        self.signals_connection()

    def init_ui(self):
        ...
        self.buttonBox = QtGui.QDialogButtonBox()
        self.buttonBox.addButton("Help", QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.HelpRole)
        self.buttonBox.addButton("Apply", QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.AcceptRole)
        self.buttonBox.addButton("Cancel", QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.RejectRole)
        #

    def signals_connection(self):
        self.test_random.clicked.connect(self.test_rand)

        # Is this the latest/correct way to write it?
        self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.test_apply)
        self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.test_cancel)
        self.buttonBox.helpRequested.connect(self.test_help)

    def test_apply(self):
        print "I am clicking on Apply"

    def test_cancel(self):
        print "I am clicking on Cancel"
        self.close()

    def test_help(self):
        print "I am clicking for Help!"
```

My questions are as follows:

1. Under my function - signals_connection(), the lines that I wrote for
   the `buttonBox` (though the code still works) are quite different
   for the signal I have wrote for the `self.test_random`  and I am
   unable to find any similar online for the qdialogbuttonbox.. There
   is another style that I have found - `self.connect(self.buttonBox,
   QtCore.SIGNAL("accepted()"), self, QtCore.SLOT("accept()"))` but I
   think that is the old style?? Otherwise what should be the right way
   to write it?
2. In my `test_cancel()` function, is writing `self.close()` the best
   way to close the application? The way that I run my program is as
   follows:

   `dialog = testDialog();dialog.show()`
3. Lastly, is it possible to add 3 different tool tips to the 3 buttons I have created? I saw that there is a command for it  - `self.buttonBox.setToolTip("Buttons for life!")`, but this will results in all 3 buttons to have the same tool tip. Can I make it as individual?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Yes, that is the correct way to write signal connections (the other syntax you found is indeed the old way of doing it).  You can find all the signals in the pyqt documentation for [`QDialogButtonBox`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qdialogbuttonbox.html).  Different widgets and objects have different signals.  `QPushButton`'s and `QDialogButtonBox`'s have different signals.
2. Yes, `close()` will close the dialog.  The `QApplication` will exit by default if there are no other windows open.  However, if this is a modal dialog, you typically want to close a dialog with either the `accept` or `reject` command.  This will alert the calling function as to whether the dialog was closed with the `Ok/Yes/Apply` button or closed with the `No/Cancel` button.
3. You can set different tooltips for different buttons in the `QDialogButtonBox`.  You just need to get a reference to the specific button you want to set the tooltip for.

For example

```
self.buttonBox.button(QDialogButtonBox.Help).setToolTip('Help Tooltip')
self.buttonBox.button(QDialogButtonBox.Ok).setToolTip('Apply Tooltip')
```

Or you could loop through all the buttons

```
for button in self.buttonBox.buttons():
    if button.text() == 'Help':
        button.setToolTip('Help Tooltip')
    elif button.text() == 'Apply':
        button.setToolTip('Apply Tooltip')
```

Also, you could connect the `accepted` and `rejected` signals from the `QDialogButtonBox` to the `accept` and `reject` slots on the `QDialog`

```
self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept)
self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)
```

That way, you won't have to manually connect the `Ok` and `Cancel` buttons to your callbacks for closing the dialog.

Comment: thanks for the descriptive information. As I am not using the standard buttons given by the QDialogButtonBox, rather I create my buttons manually using `addButton`, it appears that I am unable to use the first method for setting the tooltip that you have mentioned. However it does works if I loop it via the text, which works great! 
By using `self.close()` or `self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)`, though you have mentioned that the application will still close, but will it exists anywhere in the memory?

Comment: @dissidia Yes, if you still have a reference to the dialog, then the dialog object will still exist and you can still access it's sub controls and widgets.  If you delete your references to it, eventually it will get garbage collected and cease to exist.

Comment: what will be the best way to make a clean-close of the application?